# Random Characters in the end of every image url in post

Tags: images, attachments

I am having this strange issue, whenever a post is published the images url gets random characters in the end. i have checked teh functions.php but didn't find anything related. here is an example :
wp-content/uploads/2012/10/PhotoshopSkillz.jpg?9d7bd4

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was added because of w3 total cache. if anyone else having this issue you can uncheck the "Prevent caching of objects after settings change " in the browser cache page , under media block in w3 total cache settings.